# How to avoid duplication on similar classes and similar methods?

Tags: java, code-duplication

#### Context

I am working with very similar classes like `RechargeResponse` or `ConsultResponse`. All of them (around 80) are generated from WSDL scheme  has the same structure. (This scheme comes from 3PP company, so I can't change this logic.)

Each of them contains inner classes: `RechargeResult` and `ConsultResult`.

I have a bunch of methods with same functionality. The only difference is that I need to call (for example) `response.get_ClassName_Result().getAny()` to check data.

#### Question

How can I escape from using in every method same code with only ClassNameMethod changed?

---

Is any solution like Generics, Reflections or some else could be used? (I think parsing classname like string is not a solution).

Code examples below:

**Similar classes:**

```
    public class ConsultResponse {
        protected ConsultResult consultResult;
    
        public ConsultResult getConsultResult() {
            return consultResult;
        }
    
        public static class ConsultResult {
            protected Object any;
            public Object getAny() {
                return any;
            }
            public void setAny(Object value) {
                this.any = value;
            }
    
        }
    }

   public class RechargeResponse {
        protected RechargeResult rechargeResult;
    
        public RechargeResult getRechargeResult() {
            return rechargeResult;
        }
    
        public static class RechargeResult {
            protected Object any;
            public Object getAny() {
                return any;
            }
            public void setAny(Object value) {
                this.any = value;
            }
    
        }
    }
```

**Similar (duplicated) method for each class:**

```
    private void validateConsult(ConsultResponse response) {
        if (response == null ||
        response.getConsultResult() == null ||              // need solution here
        response.getConsultResult().getAny() == null) {     // need solution or change here
        throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What I dont understand: your two inner classes are both static ... so what is the point of having two different inner classes in the first place? What prevents from having an outside standalone base class with the base implementation? If your inner classes in fact do different things, then your example should indicate that.

Comment: That's was not my solution. These classes comes from outside API and generated by WSDL scheme. I need to implement my logic to extract data. So I'm trying to find a solution for **validateConsult** method to not create a bunch of similar methods.

Comment: Then I dont understand your question. When the code is generated, and you cant change it, how can we help???

Comment: Apologize for confusing, I need to extract data calling similar methods by pattern of **ClassName**. Your comment with solution is good, but this will attract to change many classes (around 80) from third party. After, if they decide to make small changes all my work will be erased. So that's why I need  to find solution - to extract data calling similar methods by pattern of **ClassName**. Hope that's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is that your `get«classname»Result` method names include the class names. That makes it impossible to make it generic without using reflection. Why don't you just rename both to `getResult`? You could then use generics to make the class generic.

1. First, we define an interface which defines both `getAny` and `setAny`.

   ```java
   public interface Result {
       Object getAny();
       void setAny(Object value);
   }
   ```
2. Then we could create an implementation of `Result`, which is, for example, `ConsultResult`. You could do the same with `RechargeResult`.

   ```java
   public class ConsultResult implements Result {
       protected Object any; // You already have a getter, so this can also be private

       public Object getAny() {
           return this.any;
       }

       public void setAny(Object value) {
           this.any = value;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then we could create a base class `Response`, which defines the `getResult` method. The class accepts a type argument `T` which must implement `Result`.

   ```java
   public abstract class Response<T extends Result> {

       protected T result; // You already have a getter, so this can also be private

       public T getResult() {
           return this.result;
       }
   }
   ```
4. At last, we also create our `ConsultResponse` class. We extend it from `Response`, and we provide as type argument `ConsultResult`.

   ```java
   public class ConsultResponse extends Response<ConsultResult> {
       // The field 'result' is already present within the Response class,
       // so there is no need to include it here.
   }
   ```

Also, as GhostCat already said in the comments: what is the point of having two different inner classes in the first place? They're both the same in your example as it is currently written. You could replace them with a single base class; however, it could be that there's more members within those classes which are not shown in your example, so I left them as they were in my example.

---

For the validation you could do roughly the same.

Comment: That's good solution but I need to refactor many classes (around 80) that's came from outside API. So, I can't change their logic.

Comment: @Edward If you can't change their logic, then one thing you could do is to use reflection, since the method names contain the class name (which is a bad design, I think). The other thing you could do is to contact the API developers and ask them to change the API.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways around it, for example by creating a superclass from which `ConsultResponse` and `RechargeResponse` would be extending. The superclass would have the shared method defined, so you don't have to define it in the extended classes, unless you'd want to override it.

Another approach would be to separate the validation completely into a separate class, for example a `ResponseValidator` which would handle the validation on its own and would be included and used in the `ConsultResponse` and `RechargeResponse` classes.

It's hard to pinpoint an exact solution to this because it depends on your specific situation which we are not aware of completely.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can't change the logic of classes comes from outside API, may be other solution than modifying third party code.

Comment: @Edward you did not mention anything about it being 3rd party code until now. Sorry but I won't spend any more time on this.